# Rendering � in PHP after using the substr() method

Tags: php, unicode

I need to select just 180 characters from a MySQL database by PHP and show **read more** link for users that want to read total text. So I read all text from MySQL and use the substr() function like this:

```
$some_text = substr($total_text, 0, 180);
```

Everything is fine, but after some string char � shows up.

What is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: � is [U+FFFD ʀᴇᴘʟᴀᴄᴇᴍᴇɴᴛ ᴄʜᴀʀᴀᴄᴛᴇʀ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). It usually results from messing up badly with encodings.

Comment: `echo htmlentities($some_text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` after your code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had [this exact issue](http://j7mbo.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/php-html-polish-characters-and.html) with a language translation project I've recently been working on.

Apart from altering the charsets in your database, you can try the following after your code above:

```
echo htmlentities($some_text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're working with multi-byte characters.

Try using [`mb_substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead:

```
$some_text = mb_substr($total_text, 0, 180);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer .Yes I'm using multi-byte char but mb_substr can't help.

Comment: Even with `'UTF-8'` as forth argument or, better, with a top statement `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`?